# How to grep only matching string from this result?

Tags: macos, grep

I am just simply trying to grab the commit ID, but not quite sure what I'm missing:

```
➜  ~ curl https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases -s | grep -oE 'microsoft/vscode/commit/(.*?)/hovercard'
microsoft/vscode/commit/ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247/hovercard
```

The only thing I need back from this is `ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247`.

This works just fine on regex101.com and in ruby/python. What am I missing?

Comment: When I tested my solutions, I noticed you actually get multiple matches, not just one `microsoft/vscode/commit/ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247/hovercard`. Does your `grep` really return a single occurrence? That is why I added `exit` and `| head-1`.

Answer (score 2):

If supported, you can use `grep -oP`

```
echo "microsoft/vscode/commit/ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247/hovercard" | grep -oP "microsoft/vscode/commit/\K.*?(?=/hovercard)"
```

Output

```
ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247
```

Another option is to use `sed` with a capture group

```
echo "microsoft/vscode/commit/ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247/hovercard" | sed -E 's/microsoft\/vscode\/commit\/([^\/]+)\/hovercard/\1/'
```

Output

```
ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247
```

Comment: Tried with `-P` but `-P` isn't a valid argument (using grep in Mac OS)

Comment: @LewlSauce Do you have ggrep installed?

Comment: Nope. Never heard of it either. Not installed unfortunately.

Comment: Use -E. It should work approximately the same.

Comment: @DavidMoore The second example uses `-E` with a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that `grep` does not support extracting capturing group submatches. If you install `pcregrep` you could do that with

```sh
curl https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases -s | \
  pcregrep -o1 'microsoft/vscode/commit/(.*?)/hovercard' | head -1
```

The  `| head -1` part is to fetch the first occurrence only.

I would suggest using `awk` here:

```sh
awk 'match($0,/microsoft\/vscode\/commit\/[^\/]*\/hovercard/){print substr($0,RSTART+24,RLENGTH-34);exit}'
```

The regex will match a line containing

- `microsoft\/vscode\/commit\/` - `microsoft/vscode/commit/` fixed string
- `[^\/]*`  - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\/hovercard` - a `/hovercard` string.

The `substr($0,RSTART+24,RLENGTH-34)` will print the part of the line starting at the RSTART+24 (24 is the length of `microsoft/vscode/commit/`) index and the RLENGTH is the length of `microsoft/vscode/commit/` + the length of the `/hovercard`.

The `exit` command will fetch you the first occurrence. Remove it if you need all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
curl -s https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases |
sed -En 's=.*microsoft/vscode/commit/([^/]+)/hovercard.*=\1=p' |
head -n 1
```

- `head -n 1` is to print the first match (there are 10)`grep -o` will print (only) everything that matches, including `microsoft/` etc.
- Your task can not be achieved with Mac's `grep`. `grep -o` prints all matching text (compared to default behaviour of printing matching lines), including `microsoft/` etc. A grep which implemented perl regex (like GNU grep on Linux) *could* make use of look ahead/behind (`grep -Po '(?<=microsoft/vscode/commit/)[^/]+(?=/hovercard)'`). But it's just not available on Mac's grep.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS you don't have gnu utilities available by default. You can just pipe your output to a simple `awk` like this:

```sh
curl https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases -s |
grep -oE 'microsoft/vscode/commit/[^/]+/hovercard' |
awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'

ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247
3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316
f4af3cbf5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f
b3318bc0524af3d74034b8bb8a64df0ccf35549a
6cba118ac49a1b88332f312a8f67186f7f3c1643
c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63
ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea
7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e
83bd43bc519d15e50c4272c6cf5c1479df196a4d
e7d7e9a9348e6a8cc8c03f877d39cb72e5dfb1ff
```